# A linear dependent set contained in a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If a set of vector space $V$ over the field $F$ contains a linear dependent set $S$, then can we say that $V$ is linearly dependent?

This is my reasoning, it makes sense to me, I just don't know if it is "legal"

So, since $S$ is linear dependent, there exists $v_1 \in S$ such that $v_1\in \operatorname{span} S$.

This means that there exists $a_1,...,a_n \in F$ and $u_1,...,u_n \in S$ such that

$v_1=a_1u_1,...,a_nu_n$. Since $S$ is in $V$, all the $u$-vectors is in $V$, and $v_1$ is also in $V$, we can say that $v_1 \in \operatorname{span}V$

So we can conclude that $V$ is linearly dependent (?)

Comment: Either you are mixing up what some of the letters represent or what you are asking is completely trivial. For example the statement that there is a $v_1\in S$ such that $v_1$ is in the span of $S$ is strange, as clearly any element in $S$ is also in the span of $S$. If you mean to ask whether a vectorspace it itself a linear dependent set, the answer is yes, since it contains the $0$-vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes $V$ is linearly dependent. Let $A$ be a linearly independent subset of $V$. Consider a linear combination of vectors in $V$ say $\sum_{i=1}^n p_i a_i = \theta$ where $p_i \in \mathbb{F}$ and $a_i \in A \subset V$. As $A$ is linearly dependent you shall get non zero solutions for $p_i$s. Add all other terms of $V$ with your expression with $0$ coefficient. You shall get a linear combination of vectors in $V$ repersenting the null vector $\theta$, showing linear dependence of $V$.